# Modeling count data

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, count-data

Why do count data need to be modeled differently from the standard linear 
regression model ? Any simple example will suffice.

Comment: is this a self-study question?  If so, please add the `[self-study]` tag to the question

Comment: No. Its not a self study question. But its a question for which a clear cut answer is still not available

Comment: See the post I've linked as a duplicate - if there's something you think still needs clarification please edit your question to focus on it, if it's not covered elsewhere on  our site.